# How many involutions does $\Bbb Z/999$ have?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic, involutions

How many involutions does $\Bbb Z/999$ have?

Order of $g$ is donate by $o(g)$. And $o(g)=2$ iff $g$ is an involution.

I know that order of $\Bbb Z/999$ is $999$ but how can I check $999$ elements one by one to find the answer.

So could you give me some hint to do it?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $U(999)=(\Bbb Z/999)^{\times}$ instead? Because $\Bbb Z/999$ has no elements of order $2$ of course.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $g\in \Bbb Z_{999}$ has order two. Then, by [Lagrange's Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)), $$2=\lvert \langle g\rangle\rvert\mid \lvert \Bbb Z_{999}\rvert=999,$$ a contradiction; hence $\Bbb Z_{999}$ has no elements of order two.